# Applying Hidden Markov Model

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, statistical-inference

As I understand it, the HMM formula (see below) requires 3 parameters: *initial distribution*, *transition probabilities* and *emission probabilities*:

$$p(x_1,\ldots,x_n,z_1,\ldots,z_n) = p(z_1)p(x_1 \mid z_1) \prod_{t=2}^n p(z_t \mid z_{t-1}) p(x_t \mid z_t)$$

How can the following pieces of **"given"** information be used to calculate the 3 parameters, which in turn will compute the probability of a variable (price) at $T+1$?

(*Note:* Time series and transition matrices data are not included within post; focus is not end calculation, but rather clarification regarding the steps needed to get there).

1. The price of an item over 100 timepoints, i.e. $T=100$
2. The values of the price are between 1 and 50
3. If the market is *pessimistic* the price changes from $t-1$ to $t$ with the probability transition matrix $\operatorname{pessimist}(t, t-1)$
4. If the market is *optimistic* the price changes from $t-1$ to $t$ with the probability transition matrix $\operatorname{optimist}(t, t-1)$
5. If the market is $pessimistic$ it will remain as such with probability of $0.8$
6. If the market is $optimistic$ it will remain as such with probability of $0.7$
7. At timestamp 1, the market is uniformly in either a *pessimistic* or *optimistic* state, and the price distribution is also uniform.

I'm interpreting the phrases "at timestamp 1 the market is 'uniformly' [in a] state" and "price distribution is also uniform" to mean $p(z_1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $p(x_1 \mid z_1) = \frac{1}{50}$ respectively. Is this interpretation correct?

Further, as to the $\prod_{t=2}^n p(z_t \mid z_{t-1}) p(x_t \mid z_t)$ component, how do we calculate the probabilities $p(z_t \mid z_{t-1})$ and $p(x_t \mid z_t)$ for each $t$?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand where you are struggling, but it seems like you have the initial distribution given by point 7. points 5 and 6 give you the transition probabilities. points 3 and 4 give you the emission probabilities when you multiply everything together...

Comment: @KitterCatter: I edited post to highlight areas of confusion. Thanks.